# AutoHotKey Hot Strings auto capitalization of I

Tags: autohotkey

When I type `{space}i{space}` I would love for this to automatically convert this to the capital "I". I've scanned all through the AHK syntax on hotstrings and I'm very unclear how i can incorporate leading and trailing spaces into my hotstrings.

this does not work as I expect it to. It only works when the line starts with "i"

```
:C: i :: I `
```

This doesn't work either

```
:CO: i:: I `
```

Neither does this:

```
:C: i:: I
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `*` [option](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#Options) so you don't need to type an [ending character](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm#EndChars) to trigger the hotstring. And the `?` option so it trigger when it's inside of another word. (Might not seem like it is inside of another word e.g. here `test i` , but it is since the leading space is included)
Also the `C` option in there couldn't hurt I guess. Will just make it so it doesn't do a redundant replace if you capitalize the `i` yourself.

`` :*?C: i :: I ` ``

Comment: I just tested and it doesn't capitalize between words. e.g. `beep boo i bop` <<still lowercase

Comment: @wetin You will also need the `?` option so that it will trigger mid-word (even though it's not really mid-word).